# Use the content of a text file to form a condition

Tags: 14.04, text

I am interested in getting the content of a text file and use it in a condition like:
if(text1.txt!=text2.txt){text1.txt=text2.txt}

I am also interested in checking the line ex. : 
if(text1.txt(line 5)=text2.txt(line 2){...}

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using c++.

Comment: Oh yea. Try stackoverflow.com I thought you were talking about bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first comparison, use `cmp` (which is faster and simpler than `diff` or so):

```
if cmp "text1.txt" "text2.txt" ; then 
    echo "Both files contain the same data"
fi
```

For the second:

```
if [ "$(sed -n 5p "text1.txt")" = "$(sed -n 1p "text2.txt")" ] ; then
    echo "Lines 5 resp. 2 contain the same data"
fi
```

Comment: i got it working with <fstream>;int a; and textFile>>a but the second i didn't solve it..also it's true you are fast.Ευχαριστώ!or Thanks :)